# How are RSUs granted in the USA taxed in Canada?

Tags: usa, canada, taxes, tax-treaties

I am a non-resident for tax purposes in the USA.

RSUs were granted in the USA and will vest on July 15th. My USA EAD ends on July 5th and I will be on unpaid work suspension for ~10 days.

If my job's start date in Canada is July 19th, can I move physically to Canada before vesting to settle in? Or would it count as Canada sourced income if I move before vesting?

Comment: RSU taxation when changing residency between the grant and the vest may be quite complex. You also have the US State taxes (potentially, depending on the State you worked in). You should contact a professional. Ask your employer if the relocation package includes a tax service, if not - hire one yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You pay taxes to the country of residence. If you’re a citizen of the USA the you pay taxes wherever you live. The day of the move shouldn’t matter. If you live more than 183 days in Canada and have established a residence here then the CRA will have a word on your income.

Have you contacted the official website? https://www.canada.ca/en/services/taxes/income-tax/personal-income-tax.html

As usual, this is only an opinion and not professional tax advice.

Comment: "You pay taxes to the country of residence." Income is also taxable by the country of the source of income, even if it is not the country of residence.